# Calculating days difference from 2 date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables in my schemas: **employee** and **dept_emp**.

**employee** table contains all employees' data: ***emp_no, first_name, last_name, hire_date*** (when is employee started working for the company). The **employee** table will some kind looks like this

| emp_no | first_name | last_name | hire_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | Liam | Nelson | 1997-01-02 |
| 10002 | Freddie | Mercury | 1998-01-02 |
| 10003 | Phil | Foden | 1999-01-02 |

On another hand, **dept_emp** table shows in which department every employee works in. One employee can work in > 1 dept in different periods of time. For example, Emp 1 can work on Dept 2 from 01-01-1990 until 31-12-1991 then move on to work in Dept 2 from 01-01-1992. The table consists of ***emp_no, dept_no, from_date*** (when that employee started working for that dept), ***to_date*** (when that employee started working for that dept). The **dept_emp** table will some kind looks like this:

| emp_no | dept_no | from_date | to_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10001 | 0001 | 1997-01-02 | 9999-01-02 |
| 10002 | 0002 | 1998-01-02 | 1999-03-15 |
| 10002 | 0004 | 1999-03-16 | 2001-01-02 |
| 10003 | 0003 | 1999-01-02 | 2001-04-08 |

Based on the table, For all of the employees that are still currently working for the company, The ***to_date*** field in the **dept_emp** table is filled with '9999-01-01' (to show no resignation date yet) whilst for the employee that has resigned The ***to_date*** field is filled with their resignation date.

Now for the case, I want to **calculate how many days have every employee worked** for the company **but only for those who already resigned**. I figured out that to achieve the result, I would have to subtract the resignation date from the max(***to_date***) field with the min(***from_date***). Notice that I give the *max* function for the ***to_date*** because I want the SQL to extract the date which an employee resigned from his last department while I give the *min* function for the ***from_date*** because I want the SQL to extract the date which an employee started in his first department

I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_no,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    e.hire_date,
    d.to_date,
    MAX(d.to_date) - MIN(d.from_date) AS days_employed
FROM
    employees e
        JOIN
    dept_emp d ON e.emp_no = d.emp_no
GROUP BY e.emp_no
HAVING MAX(d.to_date) < SYSDATE();
```

When I run that query, the result doesn't make any sense
[This is the result that I get from the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bu7i.png)

The days_employed gave me thousands of days while the employee actually only worked for several years.

Comment: what is the output you are getting and what is the expected output

Comment: Can you quickly make a sql fiddle? It will be easier to try out queries on them

Comment: The output I am getting is the image attached. The calculation made no sense because the SQL shows that every employee has worked for tens of thousands of days while he actually only worked for several years

Comment: I have added the sql fiddle.

Comment: I think it would be more usual to store null dates as null.

Comment: @Strawberry yes i thought so too, but the schemas is from one of the sql course im currently taking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    e.emp_no,
    e.first_name,
    e.last_name,
    e.hire_date,
    MAX(d.to_date),
    DATEDIFF(MAX(d.to_date),MIN(d.from_date)) AS days_employed
FROM
    employee e
        JOIN
    dept_emp d ON e.emp_no = d.emp_no
GROUP BY e.emp_no
HAVING MAX(d.to_date) < SYSDATE();
```

The answer is here in the fiddle :
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/21a87c/10

Comment: Thanks a lot broo! Turns out it need to use the DATEDIFF function. I thought date difference can be calculated using the usula subtratcting logic.